# How to put a condition on HTTP.POST?

Tags: programming, http

I set my code to if it executes HTTP.POST, the count will reset / back to zero, but I noticed that even it returns other http code than 201 (-1 or 500), the count still resets.

How to put a condition here that `if httpResponseCode = 201 (successful), then reset (total = 0;) else http.end().`

Thanks!

```cpp
void loop () {
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
      HTTPClient http;
      http.begin(serverName);

      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      char temp[32];
      snprintf(temp, 32, "{\"amount\":\"%.2f\"}", total);
      int httpResponseCode = http.POST(temp);
     
      Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
      Serial.println(total);
      total = 0;
        
      http.end();
    }

void count () {
  total += rainrate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
if( httpResponseCode==201 )
  total = 0;
```

Your entire code would then become:

```cpp
void loop () {

  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {

    if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
      HTTPClient http;
      
      http.begin(serverName);

      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

      char temp[32];
      snprintf(temp, 32, "{\"amount\":\"%.2f\"}", total);
      int httpResponseCode = http.POST(temp);

     
      Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
      Serial.println(total);

      if( httpResponseCode==201 )
        total = 0;
        
      http.end();
    }

void count () {
 total += rainrate;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying that earlier, I'm just missing `==` lol. btw Thank you! :)

Comment: @Giddsec That's a mistake I still occasionally make. Glad you got it working now. Cheers.